# disable template member function if return type is an array

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

https://www.godbolt.org/z/_4aqsF:

```
template <typename T> struct Container
{
    template <typename TPred> T find_if(TPred pred);  // the culprit
};

template <typename T> Container<T> MakeContainer(T const &)
{
    return Container<T>();    
}

int main()
{
    auto x = MakeContainer("Hello!");
}
```

gcc, clang and msvc apparently agree that this cannot compile because find_if would return an array.

(I would have assumed that the member template isn't instantiated since it doesn't get used - apparently, this simplistic view is wrong.)

Why does SFINAE not apply here?

Is there a way to exclude the member template for types where T is not a returnable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use SFINAE on `fidn_if` you need to use dependent parameters of the function itself, here's a version that SFINAE on non-returnable types:

```
template <typename TPred, class U = T, typename std::enable_if<
       std::is_same<T, U>::value
    && !std::is_abstract<U>::value
    && !std::is_function<U>::value
    && !std::is_array<U>::value
    , bool>::type = true>
U find_if(TPred pred);
```

Comment: Accepting this answer, because it seems to most formally / portably / code-explicitely answer my question. Still, learnt fun and good things from everyone here!

Answer (score 4):

SFINAE is not in play because the members of the types produced in your `MakeContainer` return point are not examined during SFINAE of `MakeContainer` overloads.

SFINAE happens only in an immediate context.  Bodies of types and functions are not in-scope and do not cause a subsitution failure.

```
template <typename T=char[7]> Container<char[7]> MakeContainer(char const (&)[7])
```

this signature is fine.

Once selected, the `Container<char[7]>` is instantiated and its methods parsed.

```
template <typename TPred> char[7] find_if(TPred pred);  // the culprit
```

there is no `TPred` that could cause this `find_if` to be a valid method, so your program is ill formed no diagnostic required.

The correct fix is:

```
template <typename T> struct Container
{
  template <typename TPred> T find_if(TPred pred);  // the culprit
};
template <class T, std::size_t N> struct Container<T[N]>:
  Container<std::array<T,N>>
{
  using Container<std::array<T,N>>::Container;
};
```

of course, `Container<std::array<T,N>>` itself needs a very special `find_if` and probably constructors.  But at least it doesn't break immediately.

Answer (score 3):

[SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) removes from overload sets the overloads which would be illegal during template argument deduction.

Here, the overload set contains only one candidate: `MakeContainer<const char (&)[7]>`. Template argument deduction ends here. No ambiguity. Everything's fine.

Then, the type `Container<const char (&)[7]>` is instantiated. And it produces a templated function (`Container<const char (&)[7]>::find_if`) whose signatures are illegal (all of them, since `T` is deduced in the context of `find_if`). SFINAE is not at play.

Now, you can add some SFINAE to your container's `find_if` function by making its return type depend on its template argument. For that, see [max66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53485549/5470596) for that.

Comment: *"Here, the overload set contains only one candidate ... No ambiguity"* - Thank you! , this aspect especially helped me understand.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
template <typename TPred, typename U = T>
U find_if (TPred pred);  // the culprit
```

SFINAE, over methods, doesn't works with templates parameters of the class. Works over templates of the method itself. So you have to make the SFINAE substitution dependant from a template parameter of the method itself.

So not `T` but `U`.

If you fear that someone can "hijack" your function explicating the template types as follows

```
auto x = MakeContainer("Hello!");

x.find_if<int, int>(1);
```

you can impose that `U` and `T` are the same type

```
template <typename TPred, typename U = T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>::value, U>::type
    find_if (TPred pred)  // the culprit
```